# Is there a way to style a webcomponent based on the container it's in?

Tags: css, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm trying to write some webcomponents that respond to a theme for the container they're in. I.e.

```
<div dataset-theme='light'>
  <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
</div>

<div dataset-theme='dark'>
  <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
</div>
```

I'd like the background color of the one in the dark theme to change to a dark color. I've tried CSS like the following inside of my shadow-root:

```
[dataset-theme='dark']
  :host
    background-color: #333
```

But it doesn't seem to respond to that at all. Is there a way for the style of a webcomponent to change based on the container it's in?

Comment: Have you tried `[dataset-theme='dark'] my-custom-element{background-color: #333}`?

Answer (score 2):

The [`:host-context()` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context()) will allow you to style the custom element depending on its context.

```
:host-context( [dataset-theme='dark'] ) {
    background-color: #333
}
```

As a complement, you can use `:host` to apply some default CSS style when the context is not defined.

Below a demo:

```js
customElements.define( 'my-custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = `<style>
            :host-context([dataset-theme="dark"]) { 
              background-color: darkblue ; 
              color: lightgray ;
            }
            :host-context([dataset-theme="light"]) { 
              background-color: lightyellow ;
              color: orange ;
            }
            :host {
              background-color: white ;
              color: black ;
            }
          </style>
          <slot>No</slot> Theme`
  }
} )
```

```html
<div dataset-theme='light'>
  <my-custom-element>Light</my-custom-element>
</div>

<div dataset-theme='dark'>
  <my-custom-element>Dark</my-custom-element>
</div>

<div>
    <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
CSS : 

div[dataset-theme='dark'] my-custom-element{
   background-color : #333;
}
```

It's may be work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write simple css for the same. As you may have created that component somewhere. Hence it'll function as regular html tags.

```
CSS : 

my-custom-element {
   background-color : red;
}
```